# Bootstrap tabs not moving content up

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, tabs

The content of my tabs is displaying but not properly, the second tabs content is moved about halfway down the screen and I don't know why, here is the code, any help is appreciated.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="white-bg">
      <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#1-1" class="" aria-expanded="true">Overview</a>
      </li>
      <li class=""><a data-toggle="tab" href="#1-6" class="" aria-expanded="false">Miners</a>

      </li>
     </ul>
     <div class="tabs-content">
      <div id="1-1" class="tab-pane fade active in">
       <div class="row" id="white-bg">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
         <div class="foodstuffs">
          <p style="color:white;">Welcome to Dragon Fall Version 1.0. Curently there are some errors that I am in the process of fixing such as:</p>
            <br>
           <li style="color:white;">number of miners does not change the value they contribute</li>
           <li style="color:white;">middle divider alignment</li>
           <li style="color:white;">css is excessive</li>
            <br>
          <p style="color:white;">for now I only have two miners available. Later in developement this pane will contain food and water and other statistics. Thanks!
           -Akmedrah</p>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
         <div class="row">
          <div class="player-overview">
           <div class="">
           <span class="cclstone" id="stone" title="Curent Stone">0</span>
           <span class="cclwood" id="wood" title="Curent Wood">0</span>
           <span class="cclcopper" id="copper" title="Curent Copper">0</span>
           <span class="ccliron" id="iron">0</span>
           <span class="cclsilver" id="silver">0</span>
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-5">
           <div id="greenbox-l" class=""> <span id="wood" class="">testing</span>

            <br class=""> <span id="wood" class="">testing</span>

            <br class=""> <span id="wood" class="">testing</span>

           </div>
           <div id="greenbox-l" class=""> <span id="wood" class="">testing</span>

            <br class=""> <span id="wood" class="">testing</span>

            <br class=""> <span id="wood" class="">testing</span>

           </div>
           <div id="greenbox-l" class=""> <span id="wood" class="">testing</span>

            <br class=""> <span id="wood" class="">testing</span>

            <br class=""> <span id="wood" class="">testing</span>

           </div>
           <div id="greenbox-l-b" class=""> <span id="wood" class="">testing</span>

            <br class=""> <span id="wood" class="">testing</span>

            <br class=""> <span id="wood" class="">testing</span>

           </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-2">
           <div class="">
            <div class="progress">
             <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 60%;"> <span class="sr-only">60% Complete</span>

             </div>
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-5">
           <div id="green-box-r" class=""> <span id="wood" class="">testing</span>

            <br class=""> <span id="wood" class="">testing</span>

            <br class=""> <span id="wood" class="">testing</span>

           </div>
           <div id="green-box-r" class=""> <span id="wood" class="">testing</span>

            <br class=""> <span id="wood" class="">testing</span>

            <br class=""> <span id="wood" class="">testing</span>

           </div>
           <div id="green-box-r" class=""> <span id="wood" class="">testing</span>

            <br class=""> <span id="wood" class="">testing</span>

            <br class=""> <span id="wood" class="">testing</span>

           </div>
           <div id="green-box-r-b" class=""> <span id="wood" class="">testing</span>

            <br class=""> <span id="wood" class="">testing</span>

            <br class=""> <span id="wood" class="">testing</span>

           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row">
          <div class="player-overview">
           <div class="">
           <span class="cclcobalt" id="cobalt">0</span>
           <span class="ccltitanium" id="titanium">0</span>
           <span class="cclmithril" id="mithril">0</span>
           <span class="ccladamantine" id="adamantine">0</span>
           <span class="ccldraconium" id="draconium">0</span>
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div id="1-6" class="tab-pane fade">
       <div class="row" id="1-6fix">
        <div class="col-xs-12" id="1-6fix">
         <button>test</button>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
```

I am relatively new to programming and have thus far exhausted all my resources for seeing why this isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this css:

```
.fade.in {
  display:block;
}
.fade {
  display:none;
}
```

The problem was that fade was only making the opacity of the **div#1-1** to 0, which meant that it was not hidden and was taking up space on the page. So **div#1-6** was getting pushed down.

```css
.fade.in {
  display: block;
}

.fade {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="white-bg">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#1-1" class="" aria-expanded="true">Overview</a>
  </li>
  <li class=""><a data-toggle="tab" href="#1-6" class="" aria-expanded="false">Miners</a>

  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tabs-content">
  <div id="1-1" class="tab-pane fade active in">
    <div class="row" id="white-bg">
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div class="foodstuffs">
          <p style="color:white;">Welcome to Dragon Fall Version 1.0. Curently there are some errors that I am in the process of fixing such as:</p>
          <br>
          <li style="color:white;">number of miners does not change the value they contribute</li>
          <li style="color:white;">middle divider alignment</li>
          <li style="color:white;">css is excessive</li>
          <br>
          <p style="color:white;">for now I only have two miners available. Later in developement this pane will contain food and water and other statistics. Thanks! -Akmedrah
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-9">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="player-overview">
            <div class="">
              <span class="cclstone" id="stone" title="Curent Stone">0</span>
              <span class="cclwood" id="wood" title="Curent Wood">0</span>
              <span class="cclcopper" id="copper" title="Curent Copper">0</span>
              <span class="ccliron" id="iron">0</span>
              <span class="cclsilver" id="silver">0</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-5">
            <div id="greenbox-l" class=""> <span id="wood" class="">testing</span>

              <br class=""> <span id="wood" class="">testing</span>

              <br class=""> <span id="wood" class="">testing</span>

            </div>
            <div id="greenbox-l" class=""> <span id="wood" class="">testing</span>

              <br class=""> <span id="wood" class="">testing</span>

              <br class=""> <span id="wood" class="">testing</span>

            </div>
            <div id="greenbox-l" class=""> <span id="wood" class="">testing</span>

              <br class=""> <span id="wood" class="">testing</span>

              <br class=""> <span id="wood" class="">testing</span>

            </div>
            <div id="greenbox-l-b" class=""> <span id="wood" class="">testing</span>

              <br class=""> <span id="wood" class="">testing</span>

              <br class=""> <span id="wood" class="">testing</span>

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-2">
            <div class="">
              <div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 60%;"> <span class="sr-only">60% Complete</span>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-5">
            <div id="green-box-r" class=""> <span id="wood" class="">testing</span>

              <br class=""> <span id="wood" class="">testing</span>

              <br class=""> <span id="wood" class="">testing</span>

            </div>
            <div id="green-box-r" class=""> <span id="wood" class="">testing</span>

              <br class=""> <span id="wood" class="">testing</span>

              <br class=""> <span id="wood" class="">testing</span>

            </div>
            <div id="green-box-r" class=""> <span id="wood" class="">testing</span>

              <br class=""> <span id="wood" class="">testing</span>

              <br class=""> <span id="wood" class="">testing</span>

            </div>
            <div id="green-box-r-b" class=""> <span id="wood" class="">testing</span>

              <br class=""> <span id="wood" class="">testing</span>

              <br class=""> <span id="wood" class="">testing</span>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="player-overview">
            <div class="">
              <span class="cclcobalt" id="cobalt">0</span>
              <span class="ccltitanium" id="titanium">0</span>
              <span class="cclmithril" id="mithril">0</span>
              <span class="ccladamantine" id="adamantine">0</span>
              <span class="ccldraconium" id="draconium">0</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="1-6" class="tab-pane fade">
    <div class="row" id="1-6fix">
      <div class="col-xs-12" id="1-6fix">
        <button>test</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```